# vector values to database

Tags: java, jsp

How to store vector values to database? Simple example will help me (Beginner)

I have a vector as below and wants to save its contents to 11 columns available in database. Vector contains 11 values:

```
Vector cellStoreVector = new Vector();
```

below is the code that I tried. Is there anything wrong in Structure or syntax? It didn't provide any error nor saved values to DB.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table name (EMP_ID,FNAME, LNAME, CATEGORY, DEPARTMENT, Title, REASON, TL, START_DATE, END_DATE, ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst1.setString(1, cellStoreVector .get(0) );
    pst1.setString(2, cellStoreVector .get(1));
    pst1.setString(3, cellStoreVector .get(2));
    pst1.setString(4, cellStoreVector .get(3);
    pst1.setString(5, cellStoreVector .get(4));

            pst1.setString(11, cellStoreVector .get(10)     ;
```

pst1.execute();

Comment: I'll update the code that I tried.

Comment: @user1710288.. On a side note, you should always use an `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`. Its kind of deprecated.

Comment: Why don't you go do a tutorial on JDBC.

Comment: @aglassman : Requesting you to help me if you know any good JDBC and MS-Server 2008 PDF book or Links. Thank you. I tried few online and difficult to understand them. If you know some simple one, let me know.

Comment: ok, added an answer below with link to simple example.  I hope it helps you out.

Comment: @aglassman.. Please provide me any JSP, Servlet MVC manuals or links. Thank you.

Comment: @user1710288 If you tried several online and you can't understand either, you don't need a simpler tutorial, you need more prerequisite knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

If the above code you supplied is all you have, I can see why it did not provide any errors, and not commit to database.  You need to execute a prepared statement in order for jdbc to run and return results, or execute an insert or update.  The link above is a super simple example.

Comment: My question says, I need a simple example and you provided it. Thank you. Precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sql request is

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

You have just to build a string and give it to SQL engine.

```
Vector< String > v = new Vector<>();
v.add( "riri" );
v.add( "fifi" );
v.add( "loulou" );
String insert =
   String.format(
      "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s' )",
      v.get(0), v.get(1), v.get(2));
System.out.println( "SQL statement: " + insert );
statement.execute( insert );
```